# to be + past participle

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, passive-voice, be

I wanted to ask a lot of questions concerning this phrase:

> I always consult with my children who are affected by the decisions to
>   be made.

- What role does the particle *"to"* perform in this phrase? Whether *"to"* simply accompanies the infinitive, or has also another grammatical role?
- What role does the principal verb perform in relation to *"to be made"?*
- What does *"to be + past participle"* mean excluding from the explanation the role of the constructions *"going to be + pp"* and *"used to be + pp"?* If there are, what are the various meanings of *"to be + pp"*?

Comment: I won't attempt to answer your question. I will, however, suggest you change the syntax and grammar of the sentence somewhat. Here's one option:  "I always consult with my children who are going to be affected by the decisions I need to make." Or, "I always consult my children when I need to make a decision which will affect them." To be even more specific, just in case the mom or dad has children who are too young to be consulted (or are out of the picture), you could say "I always consult those of my children [or 'the oldest two'] who are going to be affected by a decision I make."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always consult with my children who are affected by the decisions
>   **to** be made.

1. *To* marks the [passive infinitive phrase](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Passive-Infinitive.htm) *to be made*.

> **I** always **consult** with my children who are affected by the decisions to be made.

2. The principle verb *consult* has a relatively **distant** relationship with the infinitive phrase *to be made*, which modifies *decisions*.

   *Decisions* is the agent of the passive verb *are affected* in the
   relative clause *who are affected by the decisions to be made*,

   The relative clause modifies *children* in the prepositional phrase *with my children*,

   The prepositional phrase *with my children* modifies *consult*.

> I always consult with my children who are affected by the decisions **to be made**.

3. The construction *to be + the past participle* is a [passive infinitive](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Passive-Infinitive.htm).

> Definition:
>
> An infinitive construction in which the agent (or performer of the
>   action) either appears in a prepositional phrase following the verb or
>   is not identified at all.
>
> The passive infinitive is made up of the marker to + be + a past
>   participle (also known as the -en form):
>
> *"The case is to be decided by a judge."*

Answer (score 0):

I think it only accompanies the infinitive:

- "I am to be home by eleven." ([It is expected of me that I will be/I have to be/I must be] home by eleven)
- "I am to drive there." ([It is expected of me that I/I have to/I must] drive there)