# Name of this grammatical construction

Tags: grammar, terminology, be, periphrastic-modals

for quite some time now, I've been wondering whether there is a proper name for the following grammatical construction expressing obligation:

**Is/are to be + [participle]**

For example, ''This paper is to be handed in before Monday''

The closest I've come to finding what this is, is a ''deontic periphrastic construction'', but that is not quite it either... I'm sorry if this is not the appropriate site to post this question, but I figured that it might be so obscure that less in-depth forums will not do.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Thank you DW256, for your very elaborate answer! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to be + past participle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225954/to-be-past-participle) It's the **passive infinitive**, (covered at [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/passive-infinitive-grammar-1691488) by Nordquist).

Comment: There are two constructions involved here - the _to_ + `Infinitive` construction representing the expected future (_He is to hand it in tomorrow_), which in this case has a passive infinitive (_It is to be handed in tomorrow_). Things are easier to see when you can break them down into their constituents.

Answer (score 2):

The construction in general is called a simple catenative construction which has the template (CaGEL p1177):

> (verb) + (non-finite clause allowed by verb)
>
> helped + make dinner (plain infinitival)
>
> wanted + to eat dinner (*to*-infinitival)
>
> started + eating dinner (gerund-participial)
>
> was + given dinner (past-participial)

The specific type of 'be' involved here which heads the clause (functions similarly to *helped, wanted, started, was* above) is labeled 'quasi-modal ***be***' by CaGEL p113:

> This has clear semantic affinities with the central modal auxiliaries,
> and syntactically it resembles them in having property [I] (as well as
> [A-H]). That is, it can’t appear in a secondary form: **I resent being
> not to tell anyone*, **The meeting had been to be chaired by the
> premier*. It lacks all the other modal auxiliary properties, however:
> it has agreement forms, it takes an infinitival with *to*, it can’t
> occur in a remote apodosis, and its preterites do not occur with the
> modal remoteness meaning. The label ‘quasi-modal’ indicates that in
> spite of its one modal property (and its modal meaning) this ***be***
> doesn’t in fact qualify grammatically for inclusion in that class.

The properties referred to above:

> Auxiliary Properties
>
> [A] Primary Verb Negation  *It **will** not work*.
>
> [B] Subject-Auxiliary Inversion ***Will** it rain?*
>
> [C] Emphatic polarity *I **WILL** help you*.
>
> [D] Stranding *He wont attend, but I **will**____*.
>
> [E] Exclusion of ***do*** in code **Ed will go, and I **do** too*. ("I
> will go")
>
> [F] Precede adverb/quantifier *They **will** probably/all accept.*
>
> [G] Negative Forms *It **won't** help*.
>
> [H] Reduced Forms *She'**ll** be here soon*
>
> Modal Properties
>
> [I] Only primary forms **It's expected to **will** finish soon*.
>
> [J] No agreement *She will*/**wills win.*
>
> [K] Only bare infinitival complement *It **will** be*/**to be over.*
>
> [L] Can occur in remote apodosis *If it weren't for her, I **would**
> give up.*
>
> [M] Modally remote preterite in main clause *I **would** ask you to
> treat it seriously*

Quasi-modal ***be*** does not have to be used with a passive *to*-infinitival clause:

> The president is to remain impartial.
>
> The law is to go into effect on April 3rd.

The example given contains a *to*-infinitival clause with a ***be*** passive construction (***be*** + past-participial clause).

> This paper **is** [to be [handed in before Monday]]

So, in short, according to CaGEL terminology, it's a simple catenative construction headed by quasi-modal ***be*** with a passive *to*-infinitival clause as catenative complement.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer wants to be upvoted.